# Location of Play! template parser

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to parse tags in posted strings. Where can I find the classes and methods that I can use to accomplish this inside the Play! framework? I need exactly the same functionality as Play! uses to process views templates (the files that are usually ending with .scala.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the compiler:
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/templates-compiler/src/main/scala/play/templates/ScalaTemplateCompiler.scala

Here is the compiler call:
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/652f26856356c643f4db44b6a44150183a4b4887/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayCommands.scala#L298